# HTML file not linking to CSS file

Tags: html, css

The html file is not linking to the css file. Both the files are placed side by side in the same directory. It used to work fine before but suddenly it doesn't work. I have tried everything that was mentioned in the answers to similar questions here in StackOverflow but still doesn't work.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Four card feature section</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="part1">
      <p>Reliable, efficient delivery</p>
      <h2>Powered by Technology</h2>
      <p> Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points to ensure that your project is successful.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part2">
    <div class="supervisor">
      <h3>Supervisor</h3>
      <p>Monitors activity to identify project roadblock.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="teambuilder">
      <h3>Team Builder</h3>
      <p>Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="karma">
      <h3>Karma</h3>
      <p>Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator">
      <h3>Calculator</h3>
      <p> Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Css code:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
   width: 60%;
   height: 60%;
}
```

For the folder structure please refer to this
https://github.com/swethalakshmi22/four-card-feature-section

Comment: When viewing Network tab, does css file is loaded properly? Have you tried `/styles.css`? Also please not that it's URL to file and not path to file

Comment: In the network tab it shows the css file status as failed

Comment: add your folder & file structure here

Comment: ...or provide a link.

Comment: pls share folder structure

Comment: Make sure your style-sheet name is style.css

Comment: correct file path - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`

Comment: I downloaded the project you provided on github. In your index.html you typed `href="/style.css"`. In your code you provided here you typed `href="style.css"` (without a slash). However, I removed the slash from your index.html and it worked fine. Please note that the background-color you set in the CSS is pretty similar to white. You may think it's not working even if it does. Try setting the body background-color to something clear like `background-color:red;` to see if the CSS is working or not.

Comment: I removed the slash and it works. I can't believe I missed that even though I checked the code multiple times. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have uploaded on Github it has href="/style.css" please write

here your code in the question is fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Four card feature section</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="part1">
      <p>Reliable, efficient delivery</p>
      <h2>Powered by Technology</h2>
      <p> Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points to ensure that your project is successful.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part2">
    <div class="supervisor">
      <h3>Supervisor</h3>
      <p>Monitors activity to identify project roadblock.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="teambuilder">
      <h3>Team Builder</h3>
      <p>Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="karma">
      <h3>Karma</h3>
      <p>Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator">
      <h3>Calculator</h3>
      <p> Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. After checking your code-snippet , it seems that either css style.css is not on the same location where your html file is. Please check that.
2. Can you please check the right on the folder (IIS_USER) must have permission on this to read the style.css   ?

Comment: Both the files are on the same location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!